# specifying the format of tick labels in ggplot2 without a transform using scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rpy2

I have a graph in ggplot2 (via rpy2) that formats the x axis on a log2 scale:

```
p += ggplot2.scale_x_continuous(trans=scales.log2_trans(),
                                   breaks=scales.trans_breaks("log2",
                                                              robj.r('function(x) 2^x'),
                                                              n=8),
                                   labels=scales.trans_format("log2", robj.r('math_format(2^.x)')))
```

If the x values are already in log2, how can I just apply the formatting transformation of `scales`, to make the values appear in `2^x` format, rather than a decimal log2 value? I.e. if I were to drop the `trans=` argument, how can I still format the ticks correctly?

Comment: Maybe replace `"log2"` with `"identity"` in `trans_breaks`? Although it would probably be easier just to untransform them and let ggplot do all this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that `math_format()` is in `scales` (can't check it right now), and based on Brian's answer the rpy2 version should be the following:

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib import ggplot2
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
scales = importr("scales")
p = ggplot2.ggplot(mtcars) + \
        ggplot2.aes_string(x="wt", y="mpg")) + \ 
        ggplot2.geom_point() + \
        ggplot2.scale_x_continuous(labels = scales.math_format("2^.x"))
p.plot()
```

Answer (score 2):

I can give the answer in pure R, but I don't know rpy2 to be able to translate it.

Effectively, you just specify the `labels` argument which controls how the labels are displayed; don't change the `trans` or `breaks` argument which affect the overall scaling and where the breaks appear. Using `mtcars` as an example:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = math_format(2^.x))
```

[image]

(Obviously that doesn't make sense since the weight is not already on a log base 2 scale, but the concept works.)